# CSS Animation - Question create divs from style

Tags: css, css-animations

Update from the question:

So, replying to your question the HTML file is missing since the website goes down.

But I think the [HTML file](https://web.archive.org/web/20160123223230/http://www.littlebux.com/login) is that:

```html
<body class="white-body">
  <div class="top-color mb-40">
  </div>
  <div class="container register-container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2 class="site-name">
        <a href="/web/20160123223230/http://www.littlebux.com/home">
          <span>Little
          </span>Bux
        </a>
      </h2>
      <form method="post">
        <div class="form-container">
          <p>Don't have an account? 
            <strong>
              <a href="/web/20160123223230/http://www.littlebux.com/register">Register Now.
              </a>
            </strong>
          </p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg col-lg-12">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg col-lg-12">
              <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg col-lg-12">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Captcha" id="captcha" name="captcha" autocomplete="off" style="width:196px;" maxlength="4">
              <img id="captchaIMG" border="0" src="/web/20160123223230im_/http://www.littlebux.com/?i=captcha&amp;t=56a3ff7e6c782" style="height: 45px;
                                                                                                                                          float: right;
                                                                                                                                          margin-top: -45px;
                                                                                                                                          margin-right: 58px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-checkbox ui-checkbox-primary">
              <label>
                <span>Forgot your password? 
                  <a href="/web/20160123223230/http://www.littlebux.com/login/reset">Request a new here.
                  </a>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="login" name="register" class="btn btn-lg btn-register text-uppercase">Login Now
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="56A3FF7E6C48956A3FF7E6C4C7"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <script src="/web/20160123223230js_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="/web/20160123223230js_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/js/main.js">
  </script>
```

And about your reference about the cage and box, it really make sense.. **I  think it should be**:

```html
<div class="cage">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="drop-one">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-two">
    </div>
    <div class="ripple">
      <div class="ripple l-side">
      </div>
      <div class="ripple r-side">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-three">
    </div>
    <div class="drop-four">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But that's still does not make the liquid effect, look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tcNbXww8_4#t=3m7s)

How sholud it be? Maybe I'm missing some part?

The [JavaScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20151130141204js_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/js/main.js) shows:

```
/*==========================================
    Register and Login Loader
    ==========================================*/
    /* See the PHP function loader() */
```

But I do not have access to PHP `loader()` since it is client side, however it should be showing in the HTML code? Right?
The CSS is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125114327cs_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/css/style.css)

And another question, how  is it possible that the `<div class="cage">` is not showing in the HTML? So how the site was able to display that? Maybe `web.archive.org` does not crawl this specific part of HTML code? But when I check the Youtube video, it is showing the user is in fact in the login page, so that should be the correct code. It is a bit weird for me.

Old reply ------

I want to know if is possible to create the right divs from the style?
The site that has this style was already down, but i got the css style from `archive.org`, but I'm not sure if it possible to create the divs from the style.

I think the first divs should be something like this:

```
     <div class="cage">
          
            <div class="box">
            <div class="drop-one"></div>
            <div class="drop-two"></div>
            <div class="ripple">
            <div class="ripple l-side"></div>
            <div class="ripple r-side"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="drop-three"></div>
            <div class="drop-four"></div>
            </div>

     </div>
```

But the styles has another class like `"loading-circles"` and `"circles"` and I do not any idea how to create that divs. In fact the animation should be balls kicking and it create the illusion like liquid.

You can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tcNbXww8_4#t=3m7s)
The css I got [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407203502cs_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/css/style.css)

```
     /*== FULL Page Loader ==*/
    
    .cage {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 50%;
      left: -10%;
      right: -10%;
      background-color: #27AE60;
    }
    .cage.two .box {
      -webkit-filter: url("/web/20160407203502im_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/css/style.css#goo2");
      filter: url("/web/20160407203502im_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/css/style.css#goo2");
    }
    .cage .box {
      width: 960px;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 300px;
      -webkit-filter: url("/web/20160407203502im_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/css/style.css#goo");
      filter: url("/web/20160407203502im_/http://www.littlebux.com/design/css/style.css#goo");
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
      -o-transform: translateZ(0);
      transform: translateZ(0);
    }
    
    .drop-one {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-animation: big-drop 2s ease infinite;
      -moz-animation: big-drop 2s ease infinite;
      animation: big-drop 2s ease infinite;
    }
    
    .drop-two {
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      top: 10px;
      left: 51%;
      -webkit-animation: big-drop 2s ease infinite 0.075s;
      -moz-animation: big-drop 2s ease infinite 0.075s;
      animation: big-drop 2s ease infinite 0.075s;
    }
    
    .drop-three {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      top: 10px;
      left: 51%;
      -webkit-animation: small-drop 2s ease infinite 1s;
      -moz-animation: small-drop 2s ease infinite 1s;
      animation: small-drop 2s ease infinite 1s;
    }
    
    .drop-four {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      top: 10px;
      left: 51%;
      -webkit-animation: small-drop 2s ease infinite 1.075s;
      -moz-animation: small-drop 2s ease infinite 1.075s;
      animation: small-drop 2s ease infinite 1.075s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes big-drop {
      0% {
        top: 25%;
      }
      50% {
        top: -40%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 25%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes big-drop {
      0% {
        top: 25%;
      }
      50% {
        top: -40%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 25%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes big-drop {
      0% {
        top: 25%;
      }
      50% {
        top: -40%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 25%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes small-drop {
      0% {
        top: 25%;
      }
      50% {
        top: -23%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 25%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes small-drop {
      0% {
        top: 25%;
      }
      50% {
        top: -23%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 25%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes small-drop {
      0% {
        top: 25%;
      }
      50% {
        top: -23%;
      }
      100% {
        top: 25%;
      }
    }
    .ripple {
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #27AE60;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    .ripple.l-side {
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-animation: l-side-ripple 2s ease infinite 1.2s;
      -moz-animation: l-side-ripple 2s ease infinite 1.2s;
      animation: l-side-ripple 2s ease infinite 1.2s;
    }
    .ripple.r-side {
      left: 53%;
      -webkit-animation: r-side-ripple 2s ease infinite 1.2s;
      -moz-animation: r-side-ripple 2s ease infinite 1.2s;
      animation: r-side-ripple 2s ease infinite 1.2s;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes l-side-ripple {
      0% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -30px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 25%;
        top: 0;
      }
      49% {
        top: 0;
      }
      50% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -25px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 35%;
        top: 0;
      }
      99% {
        left: 35%;
        top: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -30px;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes l-side-ripple {
      0% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -30px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 25%;
        top: 0;
      }
      49% {
        top: 0;
      }
      50% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -25px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 35%;
        top: 0;
      }
      99% {
        left: 35%;
        top: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -30px;
      }
    }
    @keyframes l-side-ripple {
      0% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -30px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 25%;
        top: 0;
      }
      49% {
        top: 0;
      }
      50% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -25px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 35%;
        top: 0;
      }
      99% {
        left: 35%;
        top: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 51%;
        top: -30px;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes r-side-ripple {
      0% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -30px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 75%;
        top: 0;
      }
      49% {
        top: 0;
      }
      50% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -25px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 65%;
        top: 0;
      }
      99% {
        top: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -30px;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes r-side-ripple {
      0% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -30px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 75%;
        top: 0;
      }
      49% {
        top: 0;
      }
      50% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -25px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 65%;
        top: 0;
      }
      99% {
        top: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -30px;
      }
    }
    @keyframes r-side-ripple {
      0% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -30px;
      }
      25% {
        left: 75%;
        top: 0;
      }
      49% {
        top: 0;
      }
      50% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -25px;
      }
      75% {
        left: 65%;
        top: 0;
      }
      99% {
        top: 0;
      }
      100% {
        left: 53%;
        top: -30px;
      }
    }
    
    
    /*== Circle Loader ==*/
    /* Soft fade-in for overlay */
    @-webkit-keyframes bg-fade {
      from{ opacity: 0; }
      to{ opacity: 1; }
    }
    @keyframes bg-fade {
      from{ opacity: 0; }
      to{ opacity: 1; }
    }
    .loading-overlay{
        display: none; /* Should be triggered with JS */
    }
    .loading-overlay .name{
      -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
      height:50px;
      width:50px;
      position:absolute;
      top: 46.5%;
      left: 50.5%;
    }
    /* position circle container */
    .loading-circles{
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:45%;
    }
    
    /* grow and fade animation 
    for .circle rings */
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {
      from{
        opacity:1;
        -webkit-transform:scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
      }
      to{
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transform:scale(2,2)translate(-50%,-50%);
      }
    }
    @keyframes fade {
      from{
        opacity:1;
        transform:scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
      }
      to{
        opacity:0;
        transform:scale(2,2)translate(-50%,-50%);
      }
    }
    
    /* style circle starting point */
    .loading-circles>.circle{
      position:absolute;
      -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
      transform-origin:0 0; /* radiate from center */
      -webkit-transform:scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
      transform:scale(1,1)translate(-50%,-50%);
      -webkit-animation:fade 1s linear infinite;
      animation:fade 1s linear infinite;
      display:inline-block;
      height:45px;
      width:45px;
      border-radius:50%;
      background:#ffffff;
      opacity:1;
    }
    .loading-circles.color>.circle{
        background:#27AE20;
    }
    /* Turn off animation for .hold */
    .circle.hold{
      -webkit-animation:none;
    }
    /* Iterate sequntially animation-delay */
    .circle.first+.circle{
      -webkit-animation-delay:.33s;
      animation-delay:.33s;
    }
    .circle.first+.circle+.circle{
      -webkit-animation-delay:.66s;
      animation-delay:.66s;
    }
```

Comment: Could you put your code (the HTML you have so far and the CSS) into a runnable snippet (use the <> when you edit) as that at least shows the drops 'bouncing' and it is clearer that it's the ripple effect that is missing. Also there's quite a lot of -webkit etc prefixed CSS which could helpfully be removed from  your CSS as well to make it easier to see what is going on.

Comment: I can immediately see that the HTML needs altering - note the space (the combinator) between .cage and .box in one of the settings - they are different elements, box being nested within cage.